# Django embed/dispaly .pdf in page

Tags: django, django-templates

I am attempting to display .pdfs that have been uploaded by users. I can display the path to the pdf but not document itself. I attempted to use "" in the template but this is not working.

At least one issue is that the incorrect path to the document is used when the template is rendered. The correct file path is media/company1/documents/012022/document.pdf. The file path rendered in the template is: /documents/document/4/documents/012022/document.pd

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from constrainedfilefield.fields import ConstrainedFileField


class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    file = ConstrainedFileField(
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            upload_to='documents/%m%Y',
                            content_types=['application/pdf'],
                            max_upload_size=2097152,
                                    )
```

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Document

...

class CompanyDocumentsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Document
    template_name = 'company_accounts/document_detail.html'
...

Here is my template:
```

```
<!-- templates/document_detail.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="section-container container">

  <div class="project-entry">
    <h2>{{ document.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ document.description }}</p>
    <p><embed src="{{document.file}}" type="application/pdf"   height="700px"     width="500"/></p>
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Try `src="{{ document.file.url }}"`?

Comment: Iain, that helped. The correct path is now returned. In the terminal I now see: "GET /media/company1/documents/012022/Joint1021S.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 3161

In the browser, where the pdf should display, I see "co1.localhost refused to connect."

Comment: Could be an issue with your media settings or urls, have you configured your urls to serve media files locally? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: I think that is the issue. I am moving over some apps to a new project and I have not set that up yet. Thank you.

Comment: This helped. I am now seeing this in the terminal when the page in question is accessed: "GET /media/company1/documents/012022/Joint1021S.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 254940. However I am still seeing the error "co1.localhost refused to connect" in the browser where the pdf should be.

Comment: Try adding this to your settings `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#x-frame-options

Comment: I thought that was going to solve it. I am seeing this error in the console:Refused to display 'http://co1.localhost:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. However I am still getting the error.

Comment: Might need to hard reset your browser and/or clear the browser cache, in Chrome if you have dev tools open you can right-click the refresh button and click "Empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: This worked. Thank you again for your help.